# Nested Loops in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using nested loops to access data of the json object to display the *id* and *type* of *topping*, however its not working. Here's my code:

```
    var j_obj = {
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "type": "Regular"
    }, {
      "id": "1002",
      "type": "Chocolate"
    }, {
      "id": "1003",
      "type": "Blueberry"
    }, {
      "id": "1004",
      "type": "Devil's Food"
    }]
  },
  "topping": [{
    "id": "5001",
    "type": "None"
  }, {
    "id": "5002",
    "type": "Glazed"
  }, {
    "id": "5005",
    "type": "Sugar"
  }, {
    "id": "5007",
    "type": "Powdered Sugar"
  }, {
    "id": "5006",
    "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
  }, {
    "id": "5003",
    "type": "Chocolate"
  }, {
    "id": "5004",
    "type": "Maple"
  }]
}
var Outer_log=[];
debugger
angular.forEach(j_obj, function(an_object){
    //Outer_log.push("ID : "+an_object.id+" type : "+an_object.type);
    angular.forEach(an_object.topping,function(innerobject){
    Outer_log.push("ID : "+innerobject.id+" type : "+innerobject.type);
  },Outer_log);
});
console.log(Outer_log);
```

Could someone please highlight the error in above code, Thanks

Comment: why do you try to do this `angular.forEach(j_obj, function(an_object){`? In think you need just one foreach  `angular.forEach(j_obj.topping,function(innerobject){
    Outer_log.push("ID : "+innerobject.id+" type : "+innerobject.type);
  },Outer_log);`

Comment: Actually I would be having multiple such objects, hence used an outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are iterating over object where as loop run over array.

hope this helps [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/32xphpf6/)

```js
 var j_obj = [{
   "id": "0001",
   "type": "donut",
   "name": "Cake",
   "ppu": 0.55,
   "batters": {
     "batter": [{
       "id": "1001",
       "type": "Regular"
     }, {
       "id": "1002",
       "type": "Chocolate"
     }, {
       "id": "1003",
       "type": "Blueberry"
     }, {
       "id": "1004",
       "type": "Devil's Food"
     }]
   },
   "topping": [{
     "id": "5001",
     "type": "None"
   }, {
     "id": "5002",
     "type": "Glazed"
   }, {
     "id": "5005",
     "type": "Sugar"
   }, {
     "id": "5007",
     "type": "Powdered Sugar"
   }, {
     "id": "5006",
     "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
   }, {
     "id": "5003",
     "type": "Chocolate"
   }, {
     "id": "5004",
     "type": "Maple"
   }]
 }]

 var Outer_log = [];
 angular.forEach(j_obj, function(an_object) {
   //Outer_log.push("ID : "+an_object.id+" type : "+an_object.type);
   angular.forEach(an_object.topping, function(innerobject) {
     Outer_log.push("ID : " + innerobject.id + " type : " + innerobject.type);
   }, Outer_log);
 });
 console.log(Outer_log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angulars `forEach` is intended to iterate over arrays not object. so if you change your code to something like this

```
var j_obj = [{ ...}] //object is wrapped inside array.
```

it will work. Another thing is you don't need a nested loop in this case. You can just do:

```
angular.forEach(j_obj.topping, function(key, value){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using nested loop you can iterate using angular.forEach like this

```
var finalArray=[];
```

angular.forEach(j_obj[0].topping, function(eachobject){

```
finalArray.push("ID : "+ eachobject.id+" type : "+ eachobject.type);
```

});